ManualRestEvent It does not work properly
When I use ManualRestEvent I expect it to increment once and decrement once but it doesn't. And after a while, the values will exceed 0 and 1, but this does not happen in AutoRestEvent.
Why is this happening?
There is a problem with my code or I am using Rest() incorrectly
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class ManualRestEventDemo
    {
        ManualResetEvent _manualResetEventINC = new(true);
        ManualResetEvent _manualResetEventDEC = new(false);
        int _count = 0;
        public void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("MANUAL REST EVENT DEMO STARTED");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            var threads = new List<Thread>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                threads.Add(new Thread(() => IncrementCounter()) { Name = $"+T{i}" });
                threads.Add(new Thread(() => DecrementCounter()) { Name = $"-T{i}" });
            }
            threads.ForEach(z => z.Start());
        }

        void IncrementCounter()
        {
            if (_manualResetEventINC.WaitOne(1000))
            {
                try
                {
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref _count);
                    Console.WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.Name}-{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}\t/ Counter Inc:{_count}");
                    _manualResetEventDEC.Set();
                }
                finally
                {
                    _manualResetEventINC.Reset();
                }
            }
        }
        void DecrementCounter()
        {
            if (_manualResetEventDEC.WaitOne(1000))
            {
                try
                {
                    Interlocked.Decrement(ref _count);
                    Console.WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.Name}-{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}\t/ Counter Dec:{_count}");
                    _manualResetEventINC.Set();
                }
                finally
                {
                    _manualResetEventDEC.Reset();


                }
            }
        }
    }
}




+T272-547       / Counter Inc:1
-T272-548       / Counter Dec:0
+T273-549       / Counter Inc:1
-T273-550       / Counter Dec:0
+T274-551       / Counter Inc:1
-T274-552       / Counter Dec:0
+T275-553       / Counter Inc:1
-T275-554       / Counter Dec:0
+T280-563       / Counter Inc:1
-T282-568       / Counter Dec:-2 //INCORRECT
-T280-564       / Counter Dec:-1 //INCORRECT
-T281-566       / Counter Dec:-1 //INCORRECT
+T281-565       / Counter Inc:0
+T282-567       / Counter Inc:-1 //INCORRECT
+T283-569       / Counter Inc:-1 //INCORRECT
-T283-570       / Counter Dec:-3 //INCORRECT
+T284-571       / Counter Inc:1
-T284-572       / Counter Dec:0
+T285-573       / Counter Inc:1
-T288-580       / Counter Dec:0
+T992-1987      / Counter Inc:131 //INCORRECT
-T992-1988      / Counter Dec:130 //INCORRECT
+T993-1989      / Counter Inc:131 //INCORRECT


What do you think happens right after EventDEC.Set() when there are 1000 threads waiting in EventDEC.WaitOne(1000)?  Obviously one wakes up.  What prevents another one, or two, or 999 from also waking up?

Part of the output is removed. My problem is that the value of the counter should not be anything but 0 and 1

//INCORRECT There are wrong outputs that should not have been printed

ManualResetEvent is not a mutex. If you set it, all threads waiting on it will be released. In contrast, AutoResetEvent will release only one thread each time you set it.

@AlirezaMolaei: They are not wrong; you are not thinking correctly about concurrency.  With ManualResetEvent, any number of threads can pass through EventDEC.WaitOne(1000), the Interlocked.Decrement, and the print (and these can be oddly interleaved across multiple threads) before any thread reaches EventDEC.Reset();
